# Will requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution nodeAffinity persist if a pod gets evicted and rescheduled?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

So, let's say we assign `requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution` type to node affinity and specify some node selector terms. Let's suppose a pod gets created according to the terms. But, what if a pod gets evicted and it is rescheduled.
Would that node affinity/node selector terms which is `requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution` be taken into account when a new pod is created?

Answer (score 4):

`requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution` type of [nodeAffinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#node-affinity), unofficially calls "hard rule" guarantee you the pod will be created/RECREATED exactly based on rules you defined.

Example from [official kubernetes documentation](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/website/master/content/en/examples/pods/pod-with-node-affinity.yaml):

```
spec:
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: kubernetes.io/e2e-az-name
            operator: In
            values:
            - e2e-az1
            - e2e-az2
```

Above spec will always recreate pod ONLY in nodes with `label=kubernetes.io/e2e-az-name` that contains values `e2e-az1` or `e2e-az2`

Answer (score 1):

Scheduling is done by Kubernetes scheduler and every time it will schedule or reschedule a pod it will consider the affinity and antiaffiny defined in pod spec.